# kinect2 sdk v1409 not supporting kinect2 sdk functions?

Tags: c++, kinect-sdk

I've installed the latest kinect2 for windows sdk, v1409, however, my kinect.h file that is installed doesn't include forward function declarations for a lot of functions that my existing code is trying to use.

for example, the IKinectSensorCollection class.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinect.ikinectsensorcollection.aspx

Has anyone else had this problem? Or does anyone know where to download the older versions of the SDK?

Comment: I have the same problem.. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @guilhermemtr no.. but I have not tried recently, considering this is 3 years ago, I'm surprised MSFT hasn't fixed the issue with the SDK spec